# JQuery draggable + Sortable - Click to add

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jQuery sortable list that can have draggable list elements dragged into it.

Is there any way of adding elements to the sortable list by clicking on them (or a separate button) rather than dragging, and triggering the sortable 'receive' event?

Comment: Have you try with jquery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable

Comment: Thanks for the info Naga, but I'm struggling to find anything in the documentation that helps solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built in way to trigger this (assuming trigger('receive') would be diffucult to get working), but here is the way i would go with it:

Add the addToList function call to your draggable list items, then create this function.  Customize the inner html / span tags as you see fit.

```
function addToList(text,id){

var $list=$("ol#drop_zone");

item_html    += "<span>"+text+"</span>";
var $listItem = $("<li/>",{
id          : id,   
html        : item_html
});
$list.append($listItem);
//bind a removeItem function to the new list item
$listItem.find('span').bind('click',removeItem);
//make a call to receive_item function that does the same as receive event
receive_item(id);
}
```

make a receive item function that is used in your drop event and in your manual addToList event:

```
function receiveItem(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $('ol#drop_zone').sortable('serialize'), 
        dataType: 'script',
        complete: function(request){
            alert('received!');
        },
        url: 'my_url'})

}
```

try this to clean up duplicate code - edit your receive function to use the above function:

```
$('ol#drop_zone').sortable({
  receive: function(ev, ui){
  id=ui.item.attr('id');    
  receiveItem(id);
  }
})
```